# Exception when using BrowserProxyInfo and SunAutoProxyHandler when calling getProxyInfo

Tags: java, proxy

I am new to Java, so please be kind :)

I've seen this code floating around (here and elsewhere) and tried it, but I get an exception when I try to use it.

The Exception is:

> java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "...\nashorn.jar" "read")

My policy file contained originally:

> grant {
>     permission java.security.FilePermission "", "read";
>   };

But I changed it to this in desperation, but it still doesn't work:

> grant  {
>     permission java.security.AllPermission "", "";
>   };

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.BrowserProxyInfo;
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.ProxyConfigException;
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.ProxyInfo;
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.ProxyType;
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.ProxyUnavailableException;
import com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.SunAutoProxyHandler;

public static void main(String[] args) throws ProxyConfigException, MalformedURLException, ProxyUnavailableException {

    BrowserProxyInfo b = new BrowserProxyInfo();
    b.setType(ProxyType.AUTO);
    b.setAutoConfigURL("http://localhost/sample.pac");

    SunAutoProxyHandler handler = new SunAutoProxyHandler();
    handler.init(b);

    ProxyInfo[] ps = handler.getProxyInfo(new URL("http://example.net"));
    for(ProxyInfo p : ps){
        System.out.println(p.toString());
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you pointed the JVM to the policy file? either `-Djava.security.policy=policy.all` on the commandline or `System.setProperty("java.security.policy" , "c:/folder/to/policy.file");`